# Is there a way to select a material for all arrows, or must it be done on a per-arrow basis?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

When aiming a bow, pressing ↑ opens the Materials list "Select a material to attach."
Is there a way to avoid having to open this menu for every arrow that you fire, if you wanted to fire the same type multiple times in a row, whether through a menu option that I have overlooked, or some upgraded ability, or weapon?

Comment: This is a great question and one I have wondered about myself.

Comment: Too bad we can't "make" elemental arrows ahead of time as far as I know, would have been great if they could. To balance, they probably could take up a bow slot for each additional stack.

Comment: At least the game remembers the last material you used, so all you have to do is briefly tap up for each subsequent arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be done per-arrow. There is no power or setting to make this any simpler, unfortunately.